# Can I model a sequence of changing horizontal lines?

Tags: functions

As part of a bigger model, I'm interested in having a constant value over a period of time that changes after a while to another constant value over another period of time. So it's not overall constant, but you get the idea. The basic representation of this would be a set of horizontal lines that look like this:

[image: see image here]

what's the closest model that I can get?

Comment: what do you mean by model? Concrete more, please.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Step_function . Check out the Heaviside function.

Answer (score 2):

You can just define a series of steps, giving something like $$f(x)=\begin {cases}1&0 \le x \lt 3\\3&3 \le x \le 5\\2&5 \le x  \end {cases}$$  This is a fine model.